# Dynamically create map using vector

Tags: clojure

I have a vector ["x" "y" "z"].

I am trying to dynamically create the following:

```
{:aggs {:bucket-aggregation
        {:terms {:field "x"},
         :aggs {:bucket-aggregation 
                {:terms {:field "y"}, 
                 :aggs {:bucket-aggregation 
                        {:terms {:field "z"}}}}}}}}
```

I currently have the following but can't figure out how to make it recursive

```
(defn testing [terms]
  {:aggs {:bucket-aggregation 
           {:terms {:field (nth terms 0)} (testing (pop terms))}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve:

```
(def my-vec ["x" "y" "z"])

(defn testing [[head & tail]]
  (when head
    {:aggs {:bucket-aggregation (merge {:terms {:field head}}
                                       (testing tail))}}))

(testing my-vec)
;=>
;{:aggs {:bucket-aggregation {:terms {:field "x"},
;                             :aggs {:bucket-aggregation {:terms {:field "y"},
;                                                         :aggs {:bucket-aggregation {:terms {:field "z"}}}}}}}}
```

This works by destructuring the input into a *head* element and *tail* elements, so each call is adding a `:field` of `head` and recursing on the `tail`.

And here's another way to solve using `reduce`:

```
(reduce
 (fn [acc elem]
   {:aggs {:bucket-aggregation (merge {:terms {:field elem}} acc)}})
 nil
 (reverse my-vec))
```

This works by `reverse`ing the input vector and building the map from the inside-out. This `reduce` approach won't result in a stack overflow for large vectors, but the first solution will.